# ReactJS: How to render a JSON object with an array

Tags: reactjs, api, rest

I'm trying to render an object with an array into an array (a JSON), that I receive from an API. I've tried a lot but I don't get with the solution.

This is the object format I receive:

```
{
    "catalogue": [
        [
            "shoes.txt",
            "trousers.txt",
            "tshirts.txt"
        ]
    ]
}
```

This is the code I'm using to call the API and render the object:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Result extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = "http://localhost/catalogue";
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ items: data }));
  }

  render() {
    const catalogue = this.state.items.catalogue;
    return <div>{catalogue}</div>;
  }
}

export default Result;
```

The only I could show in the web is this:

```
shoes.txttrousers.txttshirts.txt
```

The view I can get is something like this:

```
shoes.txt
trousers.txt
tshirts.txt
```

Would somebody help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Result extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = "http://localhost/catalogue";
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ items: data.catalogue[0] }));
  }


  render() {
    let catalogue = this.state.items.map((item, key) => (
      <li key={key}>{item}</li>
    ));
    return <ul>{catalogue}</ul>;
  }
}

export default Result;
```

Pay attention to the "[0]" in this line:

`.then((data) => this.setState({ items: data.catalogue[0] }));`

Comment: It works but it gives me the same output I get, with all the values together in the same line.

Comment: Same line ? Its div which will show each item in new line. However, try this:

render() {
      let catalogue = this.state.items.map(item => (
      <li key={item}>{item}</li>
    )       
        return <ul>{catalogue}</ul>;
      }
    }

Comment: With that I get all in the same line but with a dot at the beginning. Maybe there is a problem with the object format?

Comment: Piyush: with the code you wrote here using <li> and <ul> tags and adding "[0]" into this.setState function (for the array into array), it works! I've edited the code you paste here to mark as working answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, I missed it. The catalogue contains an array at its 0 index. Thanks 4 correcting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're looking for, but this should set you on the right track to achieving what you want eventually

Change

`return <div>{catalogue}</div>;`

to

```
return (
  <div>
    {catalogue.map(item => (
      <div key={item}>{item}</div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

This will render your each entry in your array as a separate

Comment: If you dont add key you get warning in console

Comment: I tried that but I get this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Did you include the line above the return statement inside your render body? i.e.

 `const catalogue = this.state.items.catalogue;`

Comment: Yes, I did, exactly like this:
`render() {
    const catalogue = this.state.items.catalogue;
    return (
      <div>
        {catalogue.map((item) => (
          <div key={item}>{item}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }`

Comment: May be the error using .map is because that object hasn't a key for each value. Would it be?

Comment: You will get TypeError, at first render. Initiallly, react is trying to get this.state.items.catalogue which is not there as items is empty array here. Thus, error app stuck here. I have added my answer you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the **render** method to

```
class Result extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const URL = "http://localhost/catalogue";
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({ items: data.catalogue }));
  }


  render() {
return(
       <div>
      {this.state.items.catalogue.map((item, index) => (
        <span key={index}>{item}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
)}
```

Comment: Same error that in previous answer: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Comment: Edited my answer should work now. Also, use the hooks they are very powerful and easy.

Comment: It works but it gives me the same output I've got, with all the values together in the same line, as with other answers.